# insert fields for the links in my content type

Tags: theming, 7

Good morning,
I have to put in my content type of fields to collect a variable number of links (www.example.com). how can I do to allow insertion of variable numbers of fields and how do I then access them with php?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the your question, your solution is [here](http://drupal.org/project/Link).

It gives you the chance to insert link such as field. Once you enabled the module, you can add the field through "manage field" tab of your content type.

If you want to access via php, you can use the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module.

Answer (score 0):

For every field you can define how many items it takes. Setting this to unlimited should do the trick.

1. Open the field management tab of your content type.
2. Click on edit for the link field.
3. Scroll down to "Number of values" and choose "unlimited".

To acces you node with php do a [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7) with the appropriate nid and you get everything in a neat php sructure.